# jQuery : add or append by value, not by keys (from an array)

Tags: jquery

I tried the two following piece of codes and found that in each case, values are getting added following the keys (asc). Wondering how can we add that with value (asc).

The array:

```
[14] => Activité sur les fractions
[11] => Fiche commentée: L'addition de deux nombres
[12] => Fiche commentée: L'addition de durées
```

But each time they are getting added in the following order (respecing the keys)

```
Fiche commentée: L'addition de deux nombres
Fiche commentée: L'addition de durées
Activité sur les fractions
```

The two codes :

```
var contval = content[catvalue][classvalue][questvalue];
var $el = $("#contenu");

var keys = Object.keys(contval);
for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) { 
    text += contval[keys[i]] + "<br>";
    alert(text);
}

$.each(contval, function(value,key) {
$el.append($("<option></option>")
    .attr("value", value).text(key));
});
```

Comment: It would be great if you added English strings in your code :) more readable.

Comment: can you put this in a js fiddle? And skrings is skrings, dawg.

Comment: I don't think you can do what you want easily. However, you can 'flip' your array, inverting keys and values, and it'd become trivial.

Comment: Couldn't you just sort your array in ascending order before appending?

Comment: Correction to myself: it would not be as trivial as that. I reckon your best shot is to create an array of arrays, a bit like this:
`[
{id: 14, txt: Activité sur les fractions },
{id: 11, txt: Fiche commentée: L'addition de deux nombres },
{id: 12, txt: Fiche commentée: L'addition de durées}
]`

And then sort it...